# php unset causing internal server error

Tags: php, unset

```
function deleteThing() {

    if($_REQUEST ['entry'] == "") {
        exit;
    }

    $entry = $_REQUEST ['entry'];

    $file = 'entries.json';

    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file));

    unset($json[$entry]);

    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($json));


}
```

This code is trying to delete a JSON sub item at the index $entry which is passed as a number. I'm unsure if im using unset properly or not

Comment: What is the error message in the PHP log?

Comment: json_decode decodes json as php stdClass and the error comes from trying to unset a public variable on that object. Use true as the second parameter to json_decode to get an array.

Comment: Use unlink() function if to remove file ...

Comment: Please don't put a space between the variable and the `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you need to try like this:
passing second parameter as true will return array that you have used.

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file),true);//assign as  array
if(isset($json[$entry])) { //check if it is set
    unset($json[$entry]);
}
```

if you not willing to using second param as true then you will get object.In that case you need to access like this:

```
$json->{$entry}
```

Comment: In fact, `$json[$entry]` does not exist. `$json->{$entry}` does exist (without the second param `true`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are unsetting a variable not set at all.

May be `$json` is not getting value.

Do this:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file));
if (! empty($json[$entry])) {
  unset($json[$entry]);
}
```